# USING index clause

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I saw the following statement in a db patch:

```
ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (somepk_columnname) USING INDEX;
```

I wanted to look up what USING INDEX does here, but only got from google, that it lets me specify some storage specific stuff, etc.

My question really is, what *exactly* happens here? Does the db use some default values here? Creates an index for the PK in the default tablespace? I thought that an index is created for every pk per default...

Comment: Did the statement include the index name too? I mean was it ALTER TABLE tablename ADD PRIMARY KEY (somepk_columnname) USING INDEX index_name? Also, do you use Oracle?

Comment: Yup, we use Oracle, but no name was specified. So based on Lajos' answer, it's got a default name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/clauses002.htm#SQLRF52209

> Using Indexes to Enforce Constraints
>
> When defining the state of a unique or primary key constraint, you can
>   specify an index for Oracle to use to enforce the constraint, or you
>   can instruct Oracle to create the index used to enforce the
>   constraint.
>
> using_index_clause You can specify the using_index_clause only when
>   enabling unique or primary key constraints. You can specify the
>   clauses of the using_index_clause in any order, but you can specify
>   each clause only once.
>
> If you specify schema.index, then Oracle attempts to enforce the constraint using the specified index. If Oracle cannot find the index
>   or cannot use the index to enforce the constraint, then Oracle returns
>   an error.
>
> If you specify the create_index_statement, then Oracle attempts to create the index and use it to enforce the constraint. If Oracle
>   cannot create the index or cannot use the index to enforce the
>   constraint, then Oracle returns an error.
>
> If you neither specify an existing index nor create a new index, then Oracle creates the index. In this case:
>
> The index receives the same name as the constraint.
>
> If table is partitioned, then you can specify a locally or globally partitioned index for the unique or primary key constraint.

Answer (score 2):

The response above was very helpful but I also wanted to use a specific tablespace for my unique key. This worked for me:

```
alter table tablename add constraint uk_name unique (col1, col2) using index tablespace tablespace_name;
```

Comment: Can you explain this in a bit of details?